# Can I use jQuery .wrap or .wrapInner to wrap around a set of different elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a HTML structure like so:

```
<section>
  <item>
    <ele class="blue" />
    <ele class="green" />
    <ele class="red" />
  </item>
  <item>
    <ele class="blue" />
    <ele class="green" />
    <ele class="red" />
  </item>
  <item>
    <ele class="blue" />
    <ele class="green" />
    <ele class="red" />
  </item>
</section>
```

I need to wrap the second two elements inside each `<item>` in a new div, so that it looks like the following:

```
<item>
  <ele class="blue" />
  <div class="extra-wrapper">
    <ele class="green" />
    <ele class="red" />
  </div>
</item>
```

Is it possible to use any of the jQuery `wrap` functions to achieve this? Or is there another way, without having to filter through each item, find the matching elements within, build a new string of HTML and put them back in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this you can loop over each `.blue` element, get all the following siblings and call `wrapAll()` on them, like this:

```js
$('.blue').each(function() {
  $(this).nextAll().wrapAll('<div class="extra-wrapper"></div>');
});
```

```css
.extra-wrapper {
  border: 1px solid #C00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
  <div>
    <div class="blue">blue</div>
    <div class="green">green</div>
    <div class="red">red</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="blue">blue</div>
    <div class="green">green</div>
    <div class="red">red</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="blue">blue</div>
    <div class="green">green</div>
    <div class="red">red</div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Note that I changed the `<ele />` and `<item />` element to divs as they were non-standard.

Comment: Perfect solution thanks! I would never have thought of doing it this way but it's really slick.