# Wrap multiple elements in new div without destroying them - Javascript DOM manipulation

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-manipulation

I am trying to 'de-jquery' some code.

I have a div like so:

```
<div id="main">
    <div class="blue"></div>
    <div class="green"></div>
    <div class="yellow"></div>
</div>
```

And I wish to insert a wrapper div around **all elements except the first**. The full number of elements is undetermined, there could be more.

The current solution uses jquery `nextAll` and `wrapAll` to produce the following result:

## HTML

```
<div id="main">
    <div class="blue"></div>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="green"></div>
        <div class="yellow"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

## jQuery

```
$(".blue").each(function() {
        $(this)
          .nextAll()
          .wrapAll('<div class="wrapper"></div>');
    });
```

How can I remove all jQuery from this and make it vanilla?

I cannot see any `wrap` type methods. I could grab the HTML that doesn't have index of [0] and insert it into a new div, then insert that after `.blue` but that seems messy. Is there a better way?

Comment: Could there be multiple `blue`s in a container? Are you looking for `nextAll` or `nextUntil`?

Comment: @gurvinder372 No there won't be multiple `blue`, and `blue` will always be first. But there could be other unknown eles after it.

Comment: So how exactly is this different now from your previous question, https://stackoverflow.com/q/48117422/1427878 …?

Comment: @CBroe that previous question asks how to achieve this with jQuery. This question specifically asks how to recreate this WITHOUT jQuery. Did you read?

Comment: Can someone please comment how this question is too broad. It's asking specifically how to wrap elements in a div with code examples.

Comment: @Francesca i don't see why this is too broad. if it was not deterministic i would not have created an answer with a runnable code snippet in the first place.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### edit: oh you just want to skip the first item…

#### skip this solution to the new solution at the bottom.

```js
// this is how you can grab a node.
// alternatively you could use document.querySelectorAll
// (wich will be similar to how $() works)
const blue = document.querySelector('.blue');

// if you desire to use querySelectorAll you can have something similar to
// .each() like: [...document.querySelectorAll('.blue')].map(element => {});

// this is not a necessity but keeps code a little more organized,
// instead of throwing this into line 22.
const nodes = [];
let element = blue;
while(element = element.nextElementSibling) {
  nodes.push(element);
}

// let's create a new div
const wrapper = document.createElement('div');
// and add the classname of your desire.
wrapper.classList.add('wrapper');
// now let's append all nodes:
wrapper.append(...nodes);

// and append the wrapper to the .main div:
blue.parentNode.appendChild(wrapper);

// and for the fun of it, let's display the outcome:
document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('code')).textContent = blue.parentNode.outerHTML;
```

```css
div {
  padding: 2px;
  border: 1px dotted #000;
  min-height: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
    <div class="blue"></div>
    <div class="green"></div>
    <div class="yellow"></div>
</div>
```

---

### i just realized you just want to iterate after the first child…

#### let's try this then:

```js
// let's grab the main element:
const main = document.querySelector('#main');
// you could also do this: document.querySelector('.blue').parentNode;

// now let's grab the children of that node and strip the first one:
const nodes = [...main.children].splice(1);

// now let's create the wrapper div
const wrapper = document.createElement('div');
wrapper.classList.add('wrapper');

// and append all children:
wrapper.append(...nodes);

// and ofc add the wrapper to the container:
main.appendChild(wrapper);
```

```css
div {
  padding: 2px;
  border: 1px dotted #000;
  min-height: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
    <div class="blue"></div>
    <div class="green"></div>
    <div class="yellow"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below code.

```js
var allBlues = document.querySelectorAll(".blue");
var divWrapper = document.createElement("div");
divWrapper.className = "wrapper";
for(var i = 0; i < allBlues.length; i++){
  // Iterate through all the siblings.
  var tempEle;
  while(tempEle = allBlues[i].nextElementSibling){
    divWrapper.appendChild(tempEle);
  }
}

main.appendChild(divWrapper);
```

```css
.blue{
  
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
    <div class="blue"></div>
    <div class="green"></div>
    <div class="yellow"></div>
</div>
```